# Set Index name by SearchRequest class in Nest

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

I use Nest client to use ElasticSearch .I want to search in ElasticSearch :

```
SearchRequest countRequest = new SearchRequest
{
  //Somthing
};

client.Search<Post>(countRequest);
```

On other hand :

```
client.Search<Post>(s=>s.Index("IndexName").Query(...))
```

How i can set index name by SearchRequest class search ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SearchRequest` contains an `Indices` property, so that you can specify multiple indices to search across.  In your case, you could just pass the single index like so:

```
var request = new SearchRequest
{
    Indices = new IndexNameMarker[] { "IndexName" }
};
```

Another option would be to map your `Post` type to the index it belongs to, and use the typed `SearchRequest<T>` to let NEST infer the index name.

Comment: @Radu could be too late but check my answer. might help. it worked with 5.6

Answer (score 13):

This is for those using newer versions of NEST. In 2.0.1, I am unable to find the `Indices` property in `SearchRequest`. However, you can pass them in through the constructor:

```
var request = new SearchRequest<Post>("IndexName", "TypeName");
```

I map the index and type on the `ConnectionSettings` like so.

```
ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings("url");
settings.MapDefaultTypeIndices(t => t.Add(typeof(Post), "IndexName"));
settings.MapDefaultTypeNames(t => t.Add(typeof(Post), "TypeName"));
```

Other ways to tell NEST the index and type:

```
client.Search<Post>(s => s.Index("IndexName").Type("TypeName").From(0));
```

or apply the `ElasticsearchTypeAttribute` on the type.

```
[ElasticsearchType(Name = "TypeName")]
public class Post{ }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was trying to solve a bit different task with ES v5 (json request was pushed from the file) but also had the same problem with setting the indexName. So, my solution was to add `index` querystring parameter. Using this in integration tests:

```
public static class ElasticSearchClientHelper
{
    public static ISearchResponse<T> SearchByJson<T>(this IElasticClient client, string json, string indexName, Dictionary<string, object> queryStringParams = null) where T : class
    {
        var qs = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            {"index", indexName}
        };
        queryStringParams?.ForEach(pair => qs.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value));

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
        {
            var searchRequest = client.Serializer.Deserialize<SearchRequest>(stream);
            ((IRequestParameters)((IRequest<SearchRequestParameters>)searchRequest).RequestParameters).QueryString = qs;
            return client.Search<T>(searchRequest);
        }
    }
}
```